# What was the last open tournament Anand participated in before this Gibraltar 2016 event?

Tags: tournament, famous-players, anand

When and what was the last open tournament that Vishy Anand participated in before this 2016 Gibraltar Open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1993 Biel Interzonal according to [The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/sport/other-sports/viswanathan-anand-back-in-open-tournament-after-23-years/article8154597.ece).

Comment: I would have thought the Interzonals aren't "open", but apparently the definition of an "Open" is wider (and more fuzzy) than I thought.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster I guess they mean a tournament where the Swiss system is used. You could also ask whether a tournament like the Qatar Masters Open is truly "open" when there is a minimum rating requirement of Elo 2300.

Comment: Well, there is also the term "swiss open" which would be redundant. But intuitively you're right. Apparently how you get into the tournament doesn't play too much of a role in defining a tournament as an open or not.